# Squid: how can I block plus.google.com, allowing access to google.com

Tags: squid, domain

1.I have the following block.acl file in squid:

```
.*
```

It disallows access to everything by default.

2.white.acl allows access to google:

```
google\..*
```

I wanted to disallow access to `plus.google.com` by adding it to block.acl:

```
plus\.google\.com
```

3.The order of files inclusion in squid.conf is this:

```
acl good_url url_regex "/etc/squid/white.acl"
http_access allow good_url

acl bad_url url_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
http_access deny bad_url
```

Bad is included after good.

But I still can access`plus.google.com`. How can I block it, keeping access to main google domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your allow `google\..*` is matching every [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) with `google.` in it. The allow is matched first so access is allowed.

Your rule will also be allowing any requests with `google.` anywhere in the URL, like `http://example.com/google.asp`

Additionally, Google tries to do most requests via SSL so a deny via `url_regex` plays no part in these requests (There is no URL in https).  You could do some [Man in the Middle shenanigans with squid](https://serverfault.com/a/481246/125521) to decrypt SSL comms to be able to filter via URL. Alternatively `dstdom_regex` can match on just the domain component of the URL, which will also deny the SSL connects to that domain too.

Restructure your config to specifically deny, then specifically allow, then default to deny (using `all` instead of a list)

```
acl bad_domain dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/block.acl"
acl good_domain dstdom_regex "/etc/squid/allow.acl"

http_access deny bad_domain 
http_access allow good_domain
http_access deny all
```

Then include the following in the bad list:

```
(.+\.)?plus\.google\..+$
```

And in the good list:

```
(.+\.)?google\.
```

That's not perfect as you will still be allowing some other domains with `google.` in their names (google.blah.com). The `(.+\.)?` is just a specific match for any subdomain. If you want to be more specific about the allow [this wiki article on google domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains) should help.

Comment: Won't it be better to write `(.+\.)?plus\.google\..+$` to block not only com, but national domains as well?

Comment: Going by my attempts at blocking it a while ago, all plus requests went to `.com` but your suggestion will cover any others that pop up too, added it.